# How to Limit the records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, sql-merge

I have two tables called daily and master. Daily table is truncated every day but Master table holds the data and is never truncated. Every day I run a SQL script to merge the Daily table data with Master table as below inside a stored procedure:

```
UPDATE master
SET offset = COALESCE(offset + 1, 0);

MERGE INTO master m
USING daily d
ON (m.id = d.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET offset = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (id, col1, col2, col3, offset)
  VALUES (d.id, d.col1, d.col2, d.col3, NULL);
```

This works fine but in the WHEN NOT MATCHED clause, I need to Insert only a maximum of 100 records from Daily to Master. No there is no sorting criteria for the data to be inserted. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: I'd break that out of the `MERGE` and into separate `UPDATE` and `INSERT` statements. It becomes trivial at that point.

Comment: Is there any sorting criteria for the data to be inserted(or arbitrarily), and What's the version of the DB?

Comment: @EricBrandt: please can you help what the seperate UPDATE and INSERT statement would look like ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: No there is no sorting criteria. Oracle version is 12.x

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```sql
MERGE INTO master m
USING (
  SELECT *
  FROM   (
    SELECT d.*,
           m.ROWID AS rid,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY CASE WHEN m.ROWID IS NULL
                          THEN 'Insert'
                          ELSE 'Update'
                          END
             ORDER     BY ROWNUM
           ) AS rn
    FROM   daily d
           LEFT OUTER JOIN master m
           ON (m.id = d.id)
  )
  WHERE  rid IS NOT NULL -- Update all rows.
  OR     rn <= 100       -- Only insert 100 rows.
) d
ON (m.ROWID = d.rid)     -- Use the ROWID psuedo-column to join.
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET offset = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (id, col1, col2, col3, offset)
  VALUES (d.id, d.col1, d.col2, d.col3, NULL);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=93442332f380e1239c6fc1f6cd847201)*

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to check the existence of the new records,which come from `daily`, whether exist within the table `master` or not as fetching all records from `master` while restricting them to `100` rows for the data coming from `master`.

- use `NVL2()` function to determine the existence
- filter non-existent data by using `FETCH` clause for `100` rows as using the database with version 12 without using an `ORDER BY` clause since you don't need any sorting criteria while fetching data.

So, replace the table name `daily` in your `MERGE` statement with the following subquery

```sql
(
 WITH t AS
 (
  SELECT d.*, NVL2(m.id,1,0) AS exist
    FROM daily d
    LEFT JOIN master m
      ON m.id = d.id 
 )
 SELECT *
   FROM t
  WHERE exist = 1
  UNION ALL
(SELECT *
   FROM t
  WHERE exist = 0
  FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY)
)
```

Thank you @MT0 for the <kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5d7b3aa23836f24eb9e431d8fd4c734e)</kbd>